# Listview does not refresh when underlying Loader data changes

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, loader

First, I'll preface my question with the fact that I'm *not using a CursorLoader*.

I'm pulling in data from a SQLlite database to populate a listview in a ListFragment.  The initial load works well, but once the data is manipulated (i.e. an addition is made to the list), the listview NEVER refreshes to show the new data.  I am implementing the Loader callbacks like so:

```
public class BillListingFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Bill>> {

private billListAdapter mAdapter;
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
private BillsDataSource mDataSource;
private BillsStoreDatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the fragment type (archive or outstanding)
 */
private static final String ARG_FRAGMENT_TYPE = "fragment_type";

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment based on type
 */
public static BillListingFragment newInstance(String type) {
    // TODO: Make the fragment type an enum
    BillListingFragment fragment = new BillListingFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_FRAGMENT_TYPE, type);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public BillListingFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bill_view_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new BillsStoreDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mDataSource = new BillsDataSource(mDatabase);

    mAdapter = new billListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.bill_row_layout);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Bill>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    BillDataLoader loader = new BillDataLoader(getActivity(), mDataSource);
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Bill>> loader, List<Bill> data) {
    for(Bill bill: data){
        mAdapter.add(bill);
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Bill>> loader) {
    mAdapter.clear();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDbHelper.close();
    mDatabase.close();
    mDataSource = null;
    mDbHelper = null;
    mDatabase = null;
}

public void reload(){
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

private class billListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bill> {
    Context context;

    public billListAdapter(Context context, int resourceID){
        super(context, resourceID);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bill_row_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView payToField = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        TextView dueDateField = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overdueField);

        payToField.setText(getItem(position).getPayTo());

        // calculate days until due
        Bill bill = getItem(position);

        // TODO: Add how many days until bill in overdue field + add color
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(getActivity());
        DateTime dueDateDt = new DateTime(bill.getDateDue());
        DateTime currentDt = new DateTime();
        int daysDifference = Days.daysBetween(currentDt.toLocalDate(), dueDateDt.toLocalDate()).getDays();

        // depending on what that differential looks like set text / color
        if (daysDifference > 1) {
            dueDateField.setText(Integer.toString(daysDifference) + " Days");
        } else {
            if (daysDifference == 0) {
                dueDateField.setText("DUE TODAY");
            } else {
                if (daysDifference < 0) {

                }
            }
        }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

I have debugged my code so I know that the onLoadFinished callback is being made after the data has been manipulated.  I also know that adapter contains the updated data at this point.  I have tried resetting the adapter via setListAdapter(mAdatper) and every notifyDataChanged-like method I can find, but to no avail.  What is going on here and how can I get the listview to update?

Comment: does `onLoadFinished` is called?

Comment: Yes. `onLoadFinished` gets called with the updated data, which is what I find to be so bizarre about this whole thing.

Comment: have  you check the for loop if the new data is really there?

Comment: Yes. I put breakpoints in the onLoadFinished callback and no only is `data` as I expect, but `mAdapter` gets populated with items as I expect.

Comment: can you post the whole class.

Comment: Added whole class.  Rest of class shouldn't be related (just Fragment boilerplate and some view logic stuffed in the custom implementation of ArrayAdapter).  The data loader / data source is mostly from [this tutorial](http://www.phloxblog.in/android-custom-loader-load-data-sqlite-database-android-version-1-6/)

Comment: why `onLoadFinished` is different from the old ppost you had?

Comment: Sorry I'm still trying things and I copied and pasted straight from my IDE. I've tried both `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter and tried just forcing the listview to use the "new" adapter after data update.  Of course neither works.

Comment: shouldn't you be calling `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` after loading all the new items in the adapter? hmm

Comment: are you performing any filtering on the adapter?